# Python/ Pandas CSV Parsing / search for value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using pandas to parse a CSV File. The CSV file contains a value for each day of the last 10 years.

The CSV looks like this:

```
production,day,year
5.0,50,2015
80.0,51,2015
190.0,52,2015
10.0,53,2015
.
.
.
2.0,50,2016
2.0,51,2016
40.0,52,2016
20.0,53,2016
.
.
```

i use the following code:

```
def calcAverageFirstYears(productionCSV):

    myFile = pd.read_csv(productionCSV)

    result = myFile[myFile['day']==52]
    print(result)
```

So I get this reslut:

```
   production   day    year
2       190.0  52.0  2015.0
9        40.0  52.0  2016.0
16       60.0  52.0  2017.0
23        6.0  52.0  2018.0
```

How can I calculte the average of these values?
How can I calculte the average of the 2015 and 2016?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#if want mean of column production
print(result['production'].mean())
```

And:

```
#if want mean of filtered year - 2015 and 2016 only
print (result.loc[result['year'].isin([2015, 2016]), 'production'].mean())
```

All values:

```
#if want mean of all years of filtered df
print (result.groupby('year')['production'].mean())


#if want mean of all years of original df
print (df.groupby('year')['production'].mean())
```

EDIT:

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and then get `mean`:

```
print (df)
   production  day  year
0         5.0   50  2010
1        80.0   51  2011
2       190.0   52  2012
3        10.0   52  2013
4         2.0   52  2014
5         2.0   51  2015
6        40.0   52  2016
7        20.0   53  2017

#get minimal year
min_year = df['year'].min()
s = df.loc[df['year'].between(min_year, min_year + 5) & (df['day'] == 52), 'production'] 

print (s)
2    190.0
3     10.0
4      2.0
Name: production, dtype: float64

a = s.mean()
print (a)
67.33333333333333
```

Comment: Thank you. It work to calculate the mean of all years or for filtered years (2015 and 2016)

But I dont know in all cases which year was the first year of production. How do I calculate the mean of the production for the first 5 years?

Comment: @relash - do you need mean of original data for first 5 years?

Comment: I need the mean for a specific day of the first 5 years . e.g. the mean of day 53 for the years 2012-2017

Comment: @relash - I think I understand, please check edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

`describe` gives the mean, median, etc for all the columns.

```
result.describe()
```

If you want the mean for each year, then use `groupby`

```
result.groupby('year').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need production mean *by day*. But the solution below can easily be switched round for production mean *by year*.

```
df = pd.read_csv('productionCSV.csv')

s = df.groupby('day')['production'].mean()

# day
# 50      3.5
# 51     41.0
# 52    115.0
# 53     15.0
# Name: production, dtype: float64

s[52]

# 115.0
```

**Explanation**

- Separate reading data from querying. There shouldn't be a need to read the file for each function call.
- Grouping by `day` and calculating `production` mean gives you average production *by day*.
- The resulting series `s` can be used dictionary-like, as the `groupby` result uses `day` as an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby and mean (I assume that you want mean of the column *production*)

```
result[['day','production']].groupby('day').mean()
```

or

```
result[['year','production']].groupby('year').mean()
```

You can also use the same approach for the whole data frame and you are going to see averages for all days / year:

```
myFile[['day','production']].groupby('day').mean()
```

or

```
myFile[['year','production']].groupby('year').mean()
```